# Find Junit.gwt.xml in inherited modules?

Tags: maven, gwt

I have many third party libraries used in my project and I don't know which one of this is inheriting `Junit.gwt.xml`. How to identify whether `Junit.gwt.xml` is inherited by a module without looking into the modules `gwt.xml` file? How we can identify by looking at the project compile output? I'm using maven to compile and build the gwt project.

Comment: This may help you to get started if you are on linux. find . -name '*.jar' | xargs -n1 jar tvf | grep '\.gwt\.xml'. If you start this at the root of your project it may point to the list of .gwt.xml files that you can look through.

Comment: Another thought that may work is to use the gwt verbose arguments.   -Dgwt.logLevel=[LOGLEVEL] for maven. Check this out http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/compiler.html . I have a feeling if you set it to spam it will tell you where the module is inherited.